How to check if a user is logged into keycloak using check-sso
I use php libraries to log into keycloak:
https://github.com/knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle
https://github.com/stevenmaguire/oauth2-keycloak
Current code for login to keycloak:
 /**
     * @Route(“/connect/keycloak”, name=“connect_keycloak_start”)
     */
    public function connectAction(RequestStack $requestStack)
    {
        return $this->clientRegistry->getClient('keycloak')->redirect(['profile', 'email', 'roles', 'openid'])
    }


      /**
     * @Route(“/connect/keycloak/check”, name=“connect_keycloak_check”).
     */
    public function connectCheckAction(Request $request, ClientRegistry $clientRegistry)
    {
        (...)
    }

How to check if a user is logged in to keycloak without redirection? Using check-sso and these libraries?
